# Position-based tag filtering in vim

Tags: vim

When jumping to a tag with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> and having multiple tag matches, one has to choose which tag to use. Is it possible to filter the multiple match menu based on things like position or active syntax group?  This way the irrelevant tags do not appear in the first place, even though they might match.

Comment: You may be interested in [committing to the vi/vim Stack Exchange site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/76728/vi-vim?referrer=cHV8RHjUmubijasUR37EQA2), which will probably be an excellent resource for questions like this once it gets enough people committed to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag list is based on the tags database query; I don't think there's a built-in way to influence the ordering (other than maybe changing the order of the different tags files in the `'tags'` option).

In order to do custom filtering, you'd have to implement an equivalent to the `<C-]>` command yourself, using `taglist()` to retrieve the tags, and then doing your custom filtering before presenting the results. As the tags may reside in different files (which may not have been loaded into Vim yet), this won't be trivial.